# Vuejs FontAwesome eye icon to show and hide password

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, passwords, font-awesome

I am trying using the font awesome eye icon to show and hide the password when the user is trying to login. The icon does show, but I am unable to show the characters entered. Could someone please help me.

Below is the html code I am using for the password. The password that you can see within the v-show and the @click function is an empty string that is within the javascript.

If someone could help me with making this work, it would be very grateful.

HTML:

```
<div class="passwordInputArea">
                        <span class="passwordEye" v-show="password">
                           <span><font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'eye']" @click="password = !password" /></span>
                        </span>

                        <input name="password" type="password" v-model="password" v-validate="'required'" placeholder="Password" class="epForm epInput pSection" id="password" />
                        <p v-show="wrong.password">
                            Password is missing or incorrect. Please try again!
                        </p>
                        <p v-show="wrong.all">
                            Login Details Incorrect!
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to swap the input between type password and text. [Something like this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GGpXPw?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do that, install this
`npm add vue-password`
The VuePassword component adds support for a toggle to hide and show the
password as well as a meter to show the current strength of the password. And the strength ranges from 0 to 4.

```
<VuePassword
   v-model="password1"
   id="password1"
   :strength="strength"
   type="password"
 />



 import VuePassword from 'vue-password';
    export default {
      components: {VuePassword,},
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div class="input-group auth-pass-inputgroup">
              <input
                v-model="password"
                :type="passwordText"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder=""
                aria-label="Password"
                aria-describedby="password-addon"
              />
              <a @click="passwordType(passwordText)"
                type="button" class="mdi mdi-eye-outline"></a>
            </div>
<script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          passwordText: "password",
      },

      methods: {
       passwordType(passwordText) {
        this.passwordText = passwordText == "password" ? "text" : "password";
       },
      },
    };
</script>
```

A solution I implemented for myself. you can apply this for yourself.